# org.testng.TestNGException: Parameter By ITestContext In Data provider

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider

**Test**

```
    public class ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider 
    {
    WebDriver driver;

 @BeforeTest(groups={"A","B"})
 public void setup()
  {
    //Create gc driver object
    System.out.println("In  ParameterByMethodInDataprovider....");
    String drivePath="E:\\Software_Testing\\Softwars-Jars\\BrowsersWithDrivers\\Chrome"
            + "\\chromedriver_win32_V2.38_supports_Chrome_65_67.exe";
    String driverComponent="webdriver.chrome.driver"; 
    System.setProperty(driverComponent,drivePath);

    driver = new ChromeDriver();                
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://google.com");
}// setup

@Test(dataProvider="SearchProvider",groups="A")
public void testMethodA(String author,String searchKey) throws InterruptedException
{
    {
        //search google textbox
        WebElement searchText = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        //search a value on it
        searchText.sendKeys(searchKey);
        System.out.println("Welcome ->"+author+" Your search key is->"+searchKey);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        String testValue = searchText.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println(testValue +"::::"+searchKey);
        searchText.clear();
        //verify correct value in searchbox
        Assert.assertTrue(testValue.equalsIgnoreCase(searchKey));
    }//tp
}//tc

@Test(dataProvider="SearchProvider",groups="B")
public void testMethodB(String searchKey) throws InterruptedException
{
    {
        //find google search box
        WebElement searchText = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        //search a value on it
        searchText.sendKeys(searchKey);
        System.out.println("Welcome ->Unknown user Your search key is->"+searchKey);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        String testValue = searchText.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println(testValue +"::::"+searchKey);
        searchText.clear();
        //verify correct value in searchbox
        Assert.assertTrue(testValue.equalsIgnoreCase(searchKey));
    }// time pass
}//tc

/*
 * Here the DAtaProvider will provide Object array on the basis on ITestContext
 * @param c
 * @return
 */

@DataProvider(name="SearchProvider")
public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(ITestContext c)
{
    Object[][] groupArray = null;
    for (String group : c.getIncludedGroups()) 
    {
        if(group.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            groupArray = new Object[][] 
                    { 
                { "Guru99", "India" }, 
                { "Krishna", "UK" }, 
                { "Bhupesh", "USA" } 
                    };
                    break;  
        }//if if(group.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))

        else if(group.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            groupArray = new Object[][] 
                    { 
                {  "Canada" }, 
                {  "Russia" }, 
                {  "Japan" } 
                    };

        }// else if(group.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        break;

      }// for (String group : c.getIncludedGroups())

        return groupArray;      
    }//dp

    }//class
```

**Error**

```
[Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Data Provider public java.lang.Object[][] DP_ParameterTypes.ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider.getDataFromDataprovider(org.testng.ITestContext) must return either Object[][] or Iterator&lt;Object&gt;[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:509)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1293)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1020)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1110)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Error   As   org.testng.TestNGException  and Data Provider public java.lang.Object[][] DP_ParameterTypes.ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider.getDataFromDataprovider(org.testng.ITestContext) must return either Object[][] or Iterator&lt;Object&gt;[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is basically because your `@DataProvider` annotated method is returning back a `null` value instead of a proper two dimensional Object Array.

The error is misleading. This has been taken care of in the newer releases of TestNG and if you were to move to using TestNG `6.14.3` (latest released version of TestNG as of today) you should see an error message such as the one below

`Data Provider public java.lang.Object[][] DP_ParameterTypes.ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider.getDataFromDataprovider(org.testng.ITestContext) returned a null value`

So please do the following:

- Upgrade to TestNG `6.14.3`
- Initialize your 2D array i.e., in your data provider method, you need to do this `Object[][] groupArray = new Object[0][0];`